# give a name to Google Chrome devtool windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, page-title

I always use different windows of Chrome during development, and for each window I have to open a devtool window as well.

Every time I have to navigate between those windows, or I have to switch between IDE and devtool, I have to click on the right minimized devtool, and sometimes it's quite difficult because they have the same title.

[image]

I know, I could press F12 again on the window I need to maximize the right devtool, or I can maximize once the right one, and then switch between IDE and the devtool with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I could use also JavaScript to change the title, but it would last just until the next reload.

I think that give a specific name to the devtool window would speed up my work. In this way, I could identify immediately which devtool I need. For example I could rename a window "mobile" and the second one "desktop".

There is any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such feature so you can request it on https://crbug.com.

Meanwhile here's a workaround:

1. open **devtools-on-devtools**
2. run this console command in its window:

   ```js
   document.title = 'whatever'
   ```
3. save this command in [devtools snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) to quickly re-run it later.

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

Comment: Wow, I learned something new...Opening devtools on devtools :O
Have you found a better way? I am trying to capture window in OBS by title and the devtools title changes everytime I run code via my IDE...

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I often have multiple servers open all day with separate DevTools, nice to be able to rename them :)